# DOM based scripting

Tags: javascript, css, dom, drop-down-menu

ok so here's my problem...
i've been following this tutorial ( http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns )
to make a css drop down menu with my wordpress blog. everything works fine... except in IE6.
now i know this is normal, and in the link i posted above there is a fix of this which makes use of DOM based scripting... is this java script?

the main question i have is.. where do i paste this code into? css, html, make a new file?
i'm new to any form of javascript.. it's boggling me a bit..

any help would be great!

Thanks!

yours truly
noobie

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is JavaScript.

As such, you can place it in a `<script>` block, preferrably inside `<head>`. (It assigns itself to `window.onload`, so the code will be executed at onload, no matter where in the page you put the code)

Answer (score 0):

*`the main question i have is.. where do i paste this code into? css, html, make a new file?`*

I suggest you take a look at the source of this sample page: 
http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/bones/. It shows the bare details of how it's implemented.

*`i'm new to any form of javascript.. it's boggling me a bit..`*

I would like to suggest you read this nice tutorial which already helped out numerous developers during the years: [w3schools.com/js](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Grz, Kris.